# is there any on-the-fly (that doesn't store intermediate iso file in the process) command line burning software for windows xp?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, dvd, burning

I have some folders with my project with about 8G of data in each of them. Once a day I create backup to DL DVDs. It would be easier for me to do it by creating a *.CMD script in every of such folder that would run burning application, that would be smart enough not to clog some deeply nested directory in my user data folder on system partition with gigabytes of temporary data unnecessary consuming and heating my notebook disk to move the data between partitions.

(It doesn't have to be pure cli app, I be happy if it only has a way to accept all necessary parameters by command line, then it is ok for me that a gui will be run.)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the windows binaries but what about using `mkisofs` and `cdrecord` from   http://smithii.com/cdrtools

But note you will need to install `cygwin` from http://www.cygwin.com and use the `cygwin` shell to run the following; which avoids temporarily storing the ISO that is being burnt.

```
mkisofs -o - /cygdrive/c/burnme | cdrecord dev=<device> -v -eject -
```

To find the `<device>` to supply try:

```
cdrecord -scanbus
```